# Using SMOTE and ADASYN to balance image dataset

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have a highly imbalanced image dataset which I am using for a classification problem.

I am looking for a technique to solve this imbalance. I have tried under sampling and oversampling but got no good results.
Is it possible to use SMOTE and ADASYN to balance the classes given that this is multi class problem and not binary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these techniques to fight class imbalance:

1. Weighted loss
   https://keras.io/models/model/#fit
   class_weight: Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented class.
2. Data augmentation